# Three Indistinguishable Dice

Tags: code-golf, number

[image: Three dice in a clear cube]

**Given three dice rolls** (integer values from 1-6) in sorted order (so as to be indistinguishable), **convert them to the sum of two fair dice** with an identical distribution.

The answer for three to one is summing them all, modulo 6. The end-result is a perfectly flat distribution, where each of the six numbers are equally likely (just like a single die).

It's easy to do this for three-to-one, by summing them all modulo 6. The end-result is a perfectly flat distribution, where each of the six numbers are equally likely (just like a single die).  Your challenge is to do the same for three-to-two.

Inspired by [standupmath's The Three Indistinguishable Dice Puzzle](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xHh0ui5mi_E). A follow-up ["solution" video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hBBftD7gq7Y) was also posted, but arguing about "elegance" of one way or another is a bit subjective. Counting characters isn't. `:D`

### Instructions

Write a program or function that accepts three **sorted** integers/digits, 1-6, and outputs or returns a single integer, 2-12, such that, for the 216 possible inputs, the outputs are distributed as:

```
 222222
 333333333333
 444444444444444444
 555555555555555555555555
 666666666666666666666666666666
 777777777777777777777777777777777777
 888888888888888888888888888888
 999999999999999999999999
 AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
 BBBBBBBBBBBB
 CCCCCC
```

(I've used hex to keep to single characters; decimal output is fine)

**Because the dice are indistinguishable, there is no intrinsic order to them, hence the sorted input. You cannot simply "drop the third" because that would be ambiguous.**

### Details

- Score is the length of the program in bytes
- The program can be a function that's called somehow, or executable script that reads from stdin, or whatever's convienent.
- No "rerolling" by getting entropy from another source

### Example (and test)

Rather than doing any sort of probabilistic testing, it's easy enough to rip through the 216 (6³) cases of all the three dice and assert that your function returns each value as many times as it should. It will be called with identical parameters (e.g. the cases `1, 2, 3` and `3, 2, 1`, ... are presumed indistinguishable and are (arbitrarily) converted to `1, 2, 3`).

An example answer (extremely brute-force and inefficient) and test suite is provided below in Python. Hopefully the test bits are clear enough to port to your language of choice, though doing stdin/stdout would be a bit different. The testing code is just for testing and not scored (though if you want to provide it for other users of your language or I/O method, that might be useful).

```
# 6x6 lists of numbers with digits sorted
LUT = [
    [[124], [133, 166], [346], [223, 355], [256], [115, 445]],
    [[233, 266], [125], [224, 455], [134], [116, 446], [356]],
    [[126], [111, 333, 555, 225], [234], [144, 366], [456], [135]],
    [[112, 244], [235], [334, 466], [145], [226, 556], [136]],
    [[146], [122, 155], [236], [113, 344], [245], [335, 566]],
    [[246], [123], [114, 336], [345], [222, 444, 666, 255], [156]],
]

def three2two(rolls):
    look_for = int('{}{}{}'.format(*sorted(rolls)))
    for i in range(6):
        for j in range(6):
            if look_for in LUT[i][j]:
                return i + j + 2

# fair distribution of the sum of two dice multiplied by 6 (because each should be hit 6x)
expected_counts = {
    2: 6,   12: 6,
    3: 12,  11: 12,
    4: 18,  10: 18,
    5: 24,   9: 24,
    6: 30,   8: 30,
    7: 36,
}

d = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
for i in d:
    for j in d:
        for k in d:
            ijk = sorted([i, j, k])
            result = three2two(ijk)
            expected_counts[result] -= 1

for key in expected_counts:
    assert expected_counts[key] == 0
```

Comment: I read the question several times and don't have the slightest idea of what it's asking for.

Comment: In addition to the problem of this challenge being unclear, code golf challenges should score by bytes rather than characters, unless you have a really good reason to override that default.

Comment: I think I get it. The question is asking us to map from three dice rolls to two dice rolls, with some constraints.

Comment: @feersum you have three dice rolls. Turn that into two dice rolls. (just need the sum though, and the dice are indistinguishable: can't tell them apart)

Comment: OK. Say I roll 4,5,6. The sum is 15. How do I make 15 with 2 dice?

Comment: You're not making that *with* two dice, you're using the three rolls to simulate two rolls.

Comment: @feersum, you don't. That's not what the question's asking for at all. Let `U(1,6)` give you a uniform random variable which selects among the six smallest positive integers (i.e. a die). Then you have to generate a random variable equivalent to `U(1,6) + U(1,6)`.

Comment: Both `(a+b+c)%6+1` and `(a*b*c)%7` convert a triple of unordered dice to a uniform single die roll, but unfortunately are not probabilistically independent.

Answer (score 5):

## [Jelly](http://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>22</s> 20 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
6ṗ3Ṣ€ṢðQ€L€Ụịḷi’:6d6‘S
```

[Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=NuG5lzPhuaLigqzhuaLDsMSg4oKs4buk4buL4bi3aeKAmTo2ZDbigJhT&input=&args=WzEsIDMsIDVd) or [simulate all 216 outcomes](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=NuG5lzPhuaLigqzhuaLDsMSg4oKs4buk4buL4bi3aeKAmTo2ZDbigJhTCjbhuZcz4bmi4oKsw4figqzhuaJzNkc&input=).

#### Background

We map each unordered triplet of dice rolls (listed with respective multiplicities) to an ordered pair of dice rolls in the following fashion:

```
[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3] -> [1,1]
[1,2,4],[1,2,4],[1,2,4],[1,2,4],[1,2,4],[1,2,4] -> [1,2]
[1,2,5],[1,2,5],[1,2,5],[1,2,5],[1,2,5],[1,2,5] -> [1,3]
[1,2,6],[1,2,6],[1,2,6],[1,2,6],[1,2,6],[1,2,6] -> [1,4]
[1,3,4],[1,3,4],[1,3,4],[1,3,4],[1,3,4],[1,3,4] -> [1,5]
[1,3,5],[1,3,5],[1,3,5],[1,3,5],[1,3,5],[1,3,5] -> [1,6]
[1,3,6],[1,3,6],[1,3,6],[1,3,6],[1,3,6],[1,3,6] -> [2,1]
[1,4,5],[1,4,5],[1,4,5],[1,4,5],[1,4,5],[1,4,5] -> [2,2]
[1,4,6],[1,4,6],[1,4,6],[1,4,6],[1,4,6],[1,4,6] -> [2,3]
[1,5,6],[1,5,6],[1,5,6],[1,5,6],[1,5,6],[1,5,6] -> [2,4]
[2,3,4],[2,3,4],[2,3,4],[2,3,4],[2,3,4],[2,3,4] -> [2,5]
[2,3,5],[2,3,5],[2,3,5],[2,3,5],[2,3,5],[2,3,5] -> [2,6]
[2,3,6],[2,3,6],[2,3,6],[2,3,6],[2,3,6],[2,3,6] -> [3,1]
[2,4,5],[2,4,5],[2,4,5],[2,4,5],[2,4,5],[2,4,5] -> [3,2]
[2,4,6],[2,4,6],[2,4,6],[2,4,6],[2,4,6],[2,4,6] -> [3,3]
[2,5,6],[2,5,6],[2,5,6],[2,5,6],[2,5,6],[2,5,6] -> [3,4]
[3,4,5],[3,4,5],[3,4,5],[3,4,5],[3,4,5],[3,4,5] -> [3,5]
[3,4,6],[3,4,6],[3,4,6],[3,4,6],[3,4,6],[3,4,6] -> [3,6]
[3,5,6],[3,5,6],[3,5,6],[3,5,6],[3,5,6],[3,5,6] -> [4,1]
[4,5,6],[4,5,6],[4,5,6],[4,5,6],[4,5,6],[4,5,6] -> [4,2]
[1,2,2],[1,2,2],[1,2,2],[1,3,3],[1,3,3],[1,3,3] -> [4,3]
[1,4,4],[1,4,4],[1,4,4],[1,5,5],[1,5,5],[1,5,5] -> [4,4]
[1,6,6],[1,6,6],[1,6,6],[2,3,3],[2,3,3],[2,3,3] -> [4,5]
[2,4,4],[2,4,4],[2,4,4],[2,5,5],[2,5,5],[2,5,5] -> [4,6]
[2,6,6],[2,6,6],[2,6,6],[3,4,4],[3,4,4],[3,4,4] -> [5,1]
[3,5,5],[3,5,5],[3,5,5],[3,6,6],[3,6,6],[3,6,6] -> [5,2]
[4,5,5],[4,5,5],[4,5,5],[4,6,6],[4,6,6],[4,6,6] -> [5,3]
[5,6,6],[5,6,6],[5,6,6],[1,1,2],[1,1,2],[1,1,2] -> [5,4]
[1,1,3],[1,1,3],[1,1,3],[1,1,4],[1,1,4],[1,1,4] -> [5,5]
[1,1,5],[1,1,5],[1,1,5],[1,1,6],[1,1,6],[1,1,6] -> [5,6]
[2,2,3],[2,2,3],[2,2,3],[2,2,4],[2,2,4],[2,2,4] -> [6,1]
[2,2,5],[2,2,5],[2,2,5],[2,2,6],[2,2,6],[2,2,6] -> [6,2]
[3,3,4],[3,3,4],[3,3,4],[3,3,5],[3,3,5],[3,3,5] -> [6,3]
[3,3,6],[3,3,6],[3,3,6],[4,4,5],[4,4,5],[4,4,5] -> [6,4]
[4,4,6],[4,4,6],[4,4,6],[5,5,6],[5,5,6],[5,5,6] -> [6,5]
[1,1,1],[2,2,2],[3,3,3],[4,4,4],[5,5,5],[6,6,6] -> [6,6]
```

This makes all outcomes equiprobable.

#### How it works

```
6ṗ3Ṣ€ṢðĠ€Ụịḷi’:6d6‘S  Main link. Argument: D (three dice rolls, sorted)

6ṗ3                     Generate lists of length 3 over [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6].
   Ṣ€                   Sort each triplet.
     Ṣ                  Sort the list of triplets.
      ð                 Begin a new, dyadic chain.
                        Arguments: A (list of triplets), D
       Ġ€               Group each; group the indices of each triplet by the
                        the corresponding values.
                        For a triplet [a, b, c], this yields:
                          [[1], [2], [3]] if a < b < c
                          [[1], [2, 3]]   if a < b = c
                          [[1, 2], [3]]   if a = b < c
                          [[1, 2, 3]]     if a = b = c
           Ụ            Grade up; sort the indices of A by those 2D lists.
            ịḷ          Retrieve the elements of A at those indices.
                        This sorts A as in the previous section.
              i         Find the (1-based) index of D.
               ’        Decrement to get the 0-based index.
                :6      Divide the index by 6, rounding down.
                  d6    Divmod; return quotient and remainder of division by 6.
                    ‘   Increment to map [0, ..., 5] to [1, ..., 6].
                     S  Sum the results.
```

Answer (score 1):

## Pyth, <s>41</s> 27 bytes

```
JSSM^S6 3+2sPtj+216xo/JNJQ6
```

[10 random testcases](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=JSSM%5ES6+3%2B2sPtj%2B216xo%2FJNJQ6&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=[1%2C+1%2C+2]%0A[2%2C+2%2C+4]%0A[2%2C+5%2C+5]%0A[3%2C+3%2C+5]%0A[3%2C+4%2C+6]%0A[3%2C+5%2C+6]%0A[4%2C+4%2C+5]%0A[4%2C+5%2C+6]%0A[4%2C+6%2C+6]%0A[6%2C+6%2C+6]&debug=0)

[Confirmation of validity.](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=JSSM%5ES6+3L%2B2sPtj%2B216xo%2FJNJb6jcSyMSM%5ES6+3+6&debug=0)

#### Conversion table:

```
2: [111, 222, 333, 444, 555, 666]
3: [112, 113, 223, 224]
4: [114, 115, 225, 226, 355, 366]
5: [116, 122, 125, 233, 244, 445, 446]
6: [126, 133, 144, 146, 255, 266, 455, 466]
7: [134, 155, 156, 166, 246, 334, 335, 556, 566]
8: [123, 135, 234, 256, 336, 344]
9: [124, 136, 235, 345]
10: [145, 236, 346]
11: [245, 356]
12: [456]
```

### Previous 41-byte solution:

I need to golf this...

```
JSM^S6 3+2f/@co,/JNNJ.u+NY*R6t+S5_S6 6TQ0
```

[Try it online!](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=JSM%5ES6+3%2B2f%2F%40co%2C%2FJNNJ.u%2BNY%2aR6t%2BS5_S6+6TQ0&input=%5B1%2C1%2C1%5D&debug=0)

#### Conversion table:

```
2: [111, 222, 333, 444, 555, 666]

3: [112, 113, 114, 115]

4: [116, 122, 133, 144, 155, 166]

5: [223, 224, 225, 226, 233, 244, 255, 266]

6: [334, 335, 336, 344, 355, 366, 445, 446, 455, 466]

7: [556, 566, 123, 124, 125, 126, 134]

8: [135, 136, 145, 146, 156]

9: [234, 235, 236, 245]

10: [246, 256, 345]

11: [346, 356]

12: [456]
```

Answer (score 1):

## CJam, <strike>37</strike> 35 bytes

Probably not golfed well. <del>But beat Pyth.</del>

```
8aq~\;[_2$>8+@7+@:U2+1$([8U4$7]])er
```

[Try it here.](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=6%2C%3A%293m*%3A%24%7BS*s%3AQ%3B%0A%0A8aQ%7E%5C%3B%5B_2%24%3E8%2B%407%2B%40%3AU2%2B1%24(%5B8U4%247%5D%5D)er%0A%0As%7E%7D%25%24e%60p)

Comment: I suggest you change that description.

Answer (score 1):

## CJam, <s>25</s> 24 bytes

```
6Zm*{$e`z}$q~:(a#6bW2t1b
```

This is a port of [my Jelly answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/80223).

[Try it online!](http://cjam.tryitonline.net/#code=NlptKnskZWB6fSRxfjooYSM2YlcydDFi&input=WzEgMyA1XQ) or [simulate all 216 outcomes](http://cjam.tryitonline.net/#code=NlptKjokOjopOmAKW3sKICAgIDZabSp7JGVgen0kUX46KGEjNmJXMnQxYgp9ZlFdCiQ2Lzpw&input=).

*Thanks to @jimmy23013 for golfing off 1 byte!*

Comment: Well, I should have read your code before posting an answer... But some simple golf: `6bW2t1b`.

Comment: @jimmy23013 Nice. Thank you!